# form echoes success without submittting anything to database. Is there something wrong with my flow control?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

Here is the code.

I really dont why it is not submitting my information.

```
<?php

//Includes mass includes containing all the files needed to execute the full script
//Also shows homepage elements without customs

include ("includes/mass.php");


//Grabbing data form POST array and storing in variables plus the date

$username   = ($_POST['username']);
$password   = ($_POST['password']);
$conpassword= ($_POST['password2']);
$firstname  = ($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname   = ($_POST['lastname']);
$email      = ($_POST['email']);
$submit     = ($_POST['submit']);
$date       = date("Y-m-d");


//Reigstration Form         

$register = "<div id='registration'> 
                <h2>Register Here!</h2>
                <form action='register.php' method='post'> 
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                Username
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <input type='text' name='username' value='$username' >
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                Password
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <input type='password' name ='password'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                Confirm Password
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <input type='password' name ='password2'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                Firstname
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <input type='text' name='firstname' value='$firstname'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                Lastname
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <input type='text' name='lastname' value='$lastname' >
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                Email
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <input type='text'  name='email' value= '$email' >
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                <input type='submit'  class='button' name='submit' value='Sign Up'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>    
                </form>
            </div>";

echo $register;         


//Check to make sure user has submitted the correct details
echo "<div id='regform'>";
    if (isset($submit))

        {
            //Querying the database for if the username already exists

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";

                       $query = mysql_query($sql);

                     $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

                                    {
                                     $dbusername = $row['username'];
                                     $dbpassword = $row['password'];
                                    } 

                if (strlen($username)<2)

                    {

                     echo ("<br>You must enter a longer username</br>");

                     exit;

                    }

                elseif (strlen($username) > 25)

                    {
                     echo ("You must enter a shorter username<br>");

                     exit;

                    }

                if ($username==$dbusername)

                    {

                     echo ("That username already exists!");

                     exit;

                    }

                elseif (strlen($password)<6) 

                    {

                     echo ("<br>'Password must be be between 6 & 26 characters'<br>");

                     exit;

                    }

                 if ($password != $conpassword)

                    {

                     echo ("<br>Your passwords dont match<br>");

                     exit;

                    }

                elseif (strlen($firstname)<=0) 

                    {

                     echo ("<br>You must enter your firstname<br>");

                     exit;

                    }

                if (strlen($lastname)<=0) 

                    {

                     echo ("<br>You must enter your lastname<br>");

                     exit;

                    }

                elseif (!preg_match('/@/',$email) || (strlen($email)<=6) ) 

                    {

                     echo ("</br>You must enter a proper email address!");

                     exit;

                    }

                if (!isset($password))

                    {
                     echo "You must enter a password!";

                     exit;

                    }

                elseif (!isset($conpassword))

                    {

                     echo ("You must confirm your password");

                     exit;

                    }

                else

                    {

                        //Encrypt the password

                        $password = md5($password);
                        $conpassword = md5($conpassword);

                        //Start Session

                        session_start();

                        //push this information to the database

                        //Submit data to database plus store exec into variable.

                        $sqlsubmit ="INSERT INTO user VALUES ('','$firstname','$lastname','$username','$password','$email','$date',)";

                        mysql_query($sqlsubmit);

                        //echo success.



                     echo "successfully submitted to the database"."<br>"."<a href='user.php'>Click Here To Go To Your Accont</a>";

                     exit;


                    }   

         }  

    elseif(!isset($submit))

        {
         echo "</br>"."Enter your info here!!!!! :))";
        }

echo "</div>";  

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update: As Quassnoi so subtly points out, you urgently need to secure your input. See the chapter [**SQL Injection**](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) in the PHP manual.

The query fails because you have an extra comma at the end of the line:

```
  $sqlsubmit ="INSERT INTO user VALUES 
 ('','$firstname','$lastname','$username','$password','$email','$date',)";
```

Use [`echo mysql_error();`](http://de.php.net/mysql_error) to find out such errors.

Also, the success message gets output, regardless whether the query fails or not. 
You want to add a condition:

```
if (mysql_query($sqlsubmit))
 echo "successfully submitted ...";
else
 echo "error submitting ..... ".mysql_error();
```

Comment: Hint: you always get more points if you embed this picture in an answer to a question like that: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Tapha you're welcome. Also check out my edited answer. @Quassnoi, you're right of course :)

Comment: is that to go into my else statement at the end? Also where can i put the session start for the session to start when the user clicks the "Go to My Account link" thanks again mate!.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the sql attack risk. Im fixing that now!

Comment: @Tapha the block is to replace the mysql_query() statement and the subsequent "success" echo. The latter I don't know - but session_start() always belongs to the head of the script.

Comment: Thanks Pekka. You've really been helpful on this

Answer (score 2):

It has been state by Pekka as well as in a comment... but since this is *very* important, I'll repeat it in a separate (community wiki) answer:

**This code is vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks of the worst kind.**

Your code is absolutely insecure. It should not be used, no excuses possible. Go read about [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) and [input sanitisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_validation) before you proceed any further.

---

[image: Exploits of a Mom]
http://xkcd.com/327/